# Creating copies of lands that are animated by Jolrael, Voice of Zhalfir

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have 5 cards in my hand and control Jolrael, Voice of Zhalfir.

At the beginning of combat, I make a land into a 5/5 Bird with flying and haste.

In second main phase I cast a Cackling Counterpart on the animated land.

Do I get a copy that is a 5/5 Bird with flying and haste ? Or do I get a land instead ?

Will my copy keep the stats (5/5 green blue bird, flying, haste) and won't revert to a land when my turn ends ?

Answer (score 2):

You will just get a land.

> 707.2. When copying an object, the copy acquires the copiable values of the original object’s characteristics and, for an object on the stack, choices made when casting or activating it (mode, targets, the value of X, whether it was kicked, how it will affect multiple targets, and so on). **The copiable values are the values derived from the text printed on the object (that text being name, mana cost, color indicator, card type, subtype, supertype, rules text, power, toughness, and/or loyalty), as modified by other copy effects, by its face-down status, and by “as . . . enters the battlefield” and “as . . . is turned face up” abilities that set power and toughness (and may also set additional characteristics). Other effects (including type-changing and text-changing effects), status, counters, and stickers are not copied.**

So basically the land becoming a creature isn't one of the things that can be copied.